# Inserting new row in SQL database unable to because of primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Whenever I try to insert a new row into this table, it gives me the error that I cannot modify the column (because it is the primary key). So i exclude it from the query, but then it returns that the query and the number of columns is different. How can I add a row, with a primary key?

Here's the code to insert:

```
var getmessages = new SqlCeCommand("Insert into chat values('" + txtSend.Text + "', '" + Environment.UserName + "', '" + user + "', '" + Environment.UserName + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "', '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "', '"+UID+"')", con);
```

Here's the primary key that I'm adding via query (as it's an update to the database)...

```
alter table chat add c_id int identity primary key
```

And then it throws me the error [image]

And if I remove the (UID) from the insert query I get this error...

[image]

Comment: You need to use SQL parameters, If anyone types in a `'` in to the chat box it will cause the program to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell SQL CE exactly what columns you are inserting into.

The first problem isn't because it's a primary key.  It's because the key is an identify field and auto generated for you.  So, let's move on.

The Second problem is simply that you are not specifying the columns you are inserting into.

The insert should look like:

```
insert into chat(field1, field2, field3) values('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

Notice the field names.  You'll have to put the actual field names you have there.

That said, the code is still pretty bad.  Although the above works, you really really really should parameterize your queries.  Even assuming this program is never actually released into the real world and assuming that you could care less if someone hacks into it... It's still good practice to do things the right way.  Oh.. and you wouldn't have problems with `'` marks.. which would cause your app to crash.

Comment: Well really it should be `values(@val1, @val2...)` but I am sure you are editing that in.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Well.. you wouldn't need the tick marks.. ;)

Comment: Tick marks? I don't see any tick marks! (never criticize before the 5 min mark :) )

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Nice. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that. Little new here to some of this. Helped a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all columns apart from the primary key in your query:

```
Insert into chat (column1, column2, ...) values (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a serious SQL error in your code; you have to use parameters and specify each column:

```
var insert = new SqlCeCommand("Insert into chat (sendCol, firstNameCol, secondNameCol, firstTimeCol, secondTimeCol, uidCol) values (@send, @name, @name, @time, @time, @uid)";
insert.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@send", txtSend.Text));
insert.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@name", Environment.UserName));
insert.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@time", DateTime.Now));
insert.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@uid", Something));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define parameter also with values in your query like below.

```
  insert into table(f1,f2,f3) values(v1,v2,v3)
```